# Errors when upgrading from Angular 1.2.0-rc3 to 1.2.0 or higher

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I upgrade the angular version from 1.2.0-rc3 to 1.2.0 or any higher version, it causes  errors which seem to be centered on the use of $parent.$index. There is no error when using 1.2.0-rc3.

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '$parent.$index' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 20 of the expression [setSelectedTable({{$parent.$index}})] starting at [$parent.$index}})].
```

(Here $parent.$index (of the array) is being passed as the argument to a method)

The corresponding html is

```
 ng-click="setSelectedTable({{$parent.$index}})" 
  ng-class="{selectedTable:{{$parent.$index}}==event.selectedTable}"
```

Both the lines, ng-click and the ng-class fail with the above error.
It appears that angular parses the ng-class code line as selectedTable:==event.selectedTable, basically nullifying $parent.$index.

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'event.selectedTable' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 18 of the expression [{selectedTable:==event.selectedTable}] starting at [event.selectedTable}].
```

Anyone know why this error? Is there a syntax change between 1.2.0rc3 and 1.2.0? What should be used in place of $parent.$index?

Comment: You are using interpolation in a directive that does not expect interpolation. I suspect that's the problem. If you can put a plnkr.com example with a version that works and one that breaks it would help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that in an ng-click?

```
setSelectedTable($parent.$index)
```

Looks to be more what you need. If not can you please paste the line of html.

**edit**
Based on your edit, it looks like both of those should be like this:

```
ng-click="setSelectedTable($parent.$index)" 
ng-class="{selectedTable:$parent.$index==event.selectedTable}"
```

What is event though? is that bound to scope?

Comment: thanks for helping look into this. Yes, one of the lines is an ng-click. The other is ng-class. I edited the question and added the html and some more detail.

Comment: you are spot on, removing the extra curly's fixed it. I don't remember exactly why the curly's were used in the first place as it has been a while since that code was written. Why would the curly's  work with rc3 without error?